# C Programming: getchar() won't accept '+' or '-' for input, but will accept '*' and '/'?

Tags: c, calculator, getchar

I'm trying to collect an operand (+,-,*,/) from input. When I attempt to do so, the * and / input is accepted, and the code works. When I input + or -, the default exception is thrown.

What is going on?! Is there some sort of problem with the + or - signs in getchar? Can I try to reference it against an ascii value?

I take it in as a float and then I getchar. Could that be the issue?

```
float result = 0.0;
float userEntry = 0.0;
char getOperand;

void main(){

printf("Calculator is on\n");
printf("Initial value is 0.0, please issue an operation in the following format: ex. +5 -5 *5 or /5. Do not add more than one number to the total.\n");
scanf("%3f", &userEntry);
getOperand = getchar();
printf("%f", userEntry);
putchar(getOperand);

switch(getOperand){

    case '+':
        printf("addition\n");
        break;
    case '-':
        printf("subtraction\n");
        break;
    case '/':
        printf("division\n");
        break;
    case '*':
        printf("multiplication\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("UnknownOperatorException is thrown.\n");
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: `getOperand` should be `int`, since `getChar()` returns an `int`. It is also not `void main()` but `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *arg[])`.

Comment: `+5` and `-5` are valid numbers.  You may want to rethink your input method.

Comment: The code accepts the operand *after* the value, but that is not how you describe the problem or what it suggests in the prompt text.  Are you sure this is the code you are talking about?  This code won't work either with the input as described - but for a different reason.

Comment: C does not support exceptions. If you compile C code as C++: simply **don't**!

Comment: Melpomene, Olaf - My professor is demanding I use it. I'm doing this *exactly* as is demanded, including the addition of the "exception" thing. It's part of the instructions. I wouldn't choose to write it this way. Jesus. Stop jumping down my throat, please?!

Comment: I'm totally new to C. Trying my best, here. Sorry I'm not super L33t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that +5 and -5 is read as 5 and -5 by the `scanf` function leaving nothing to be read by the `getchar` function. / and * is not recognized by `scanf` with the given format, and reading is stopped once these are reached, leaving them for `getchar`.

Instead you could try calling `getchar` before calling `scanf`.

Here is an excample of it working, by simply switching the calls to `scanf` and `getchar` around:

http://ideone.com/Jlx7II

Input:

```
+5
```

Ouptut:

```
Calculator is on
Initial value is 0.0, please issue an operation in the following format: ex. +5 -5 *5 or /5. Do not add more than one number to the total.
5.000000+addition
```

Comment: Yay! Thank you! :) This was perfect.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the *operand* from being interpreted as *sign*, a single `scanf()` call with an extra argument may also be used:

```
scanf(" %c%3f", &getOperand, &userEntry);//leading space instructs trailing '\n's consumed
```

without having to call `getchar()` at all.

Printout for adding `-1`:

```
Calculator is on
Initial value is 0.0, please issue an operation in the following format: ex. +5 -5 *5 or /5. Do not add more than one number to the total.
+-1
-1.000000+addition
```

Comment: And when you extend your program to loop around for another calculation, you'll need a `space` in front of the `%c` format specifier, which tells `scanf` to ignore the `newline` that was left in the input buffer after the previous loop. `scanf(" %c%3f", &getOperand, &userEntry);`

Comment: You have a great eye, @Weather Vane. Thanks for pointing me at this accidental typo with quite serious consequences!